# Extract a table-float from a TeX-typeset PDF?

Tags: tables, floats, pdf, crop, extract

I have this article which was near-certainly created with LaTeX. One of its floats is a table, and I would like to extract it from the PDF, i.e. obtain a PDF with just that figure (excluding the caption). Is there information embedded in the PDF which would enable this? Is there software for doing that?

Comment: the information (probably) is not in the pdf to do it automatically but `\includegraphics` will allow you to select the page and clip to some rectangle with the table (clipping only affects the view though the whole page data will be included internally)

Comment: You can open the pdf with a program that supports PDF import/editing, such as Inkscape, Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Draw, and then remove everything except for the table, and finally export to pdf again. Results may vary, of course. Unless the table is very complex it is probably easier to recreate it in LaTeX yourself, maybe using some smart copy paste and search and replace actions in your editor.